# Rename the file after streaming the data from remote directory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I am reading the file using below command

```
.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), GET,"payload.remoteDirectory + payload.filename").options(STREAM))
```

Once the data is stream I have an advice for handling the success and failure. I want to rename the file in case of success, **I am facing issue while renaming the remote file**. I want to rename the file and do error handling after that using similar advice.

```
.handle(service(), e -> e.advice(after()))

 @Bean
    public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice after() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
        advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
        advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        return advice;
    }



@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow success() {
        return f -> f.handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), MV, "payload").renameExpression("headers[file_renameTo]='gileName_read'")).log();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also worked on the kind-off same flow. I hope below code might help you.

```
.handle(service(), e -> e.advice(after()))
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h
                        .headerExpression(FileHeaders.RENAME_TO, "headers[file_remoteDirectory]+'archive/' + headers[file_remoteFile]")
                        .headerExpression(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, "headers[file_remoteFile]")
                        .header(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, "headers[file_remoteDirectory]"))
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), MV, "headers[file_remoteDirectory]+headers[file_remoteFile]").renameExpression("headers['file_renameTo']"))
                .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

"having trouble" is not enough information; you need to provide the actual error/stack trace etc., when asking such questions.

That said, see [the documentation about the advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#expression-advice).

> For the successful case, the message sent to the successChannel is an `AdviceMessage`, with the payload being the result of the expression evaluation. An additional property, called `inputMessage`, contains the original message sent to the handler.

So, your expressions in the MV gateway need to reflect that (e.g. `payload.inputMessage.headers[...]`) or, for the "from" name, your `successExpression` needs to set the payload to the original filename.

Finally, if you are streaming, it seems a bit premature to rename here, before you have consumed the stream.

Comment: You are right I am trying to rename the file before consuming it. In this integration flow after streaming the data I will add MV gateway. How I can make sure that the file is renamed only if the data is streamed successfully? and can you please confirm my understanding that since I am streaming the data I will have to close the stream once I have renamed the file.

Comment: You can use the advice on whatever service you have that reads the stream; just like you had it on the gateway. Yes, you must close the input stream; you must also close the SFTP session (in the `closeableResource` header, as discussed [in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#using-the-get-command-2). Framework components (`FileSplitter`, `StreamTransformer`) do this automatically.